Yishmoel and the power of teshuvo - source?
In Lech-Lecho, Yishmoel's name is mentioned. In Vayeiro, his name isn't mention. In Chayei Soro, his name is mentioned again. It seems to me that the reason for this is that, since Yishmoel did teshuvo, his name is not mentioned in relation to his sinful days in Vayeiro. Therefore, his name is only mentioned before he sinned (i.e., when he was born and when he agreed to have bris milo) and after he had done teshuvo (i.e., when burying his father and his death). I have told this to various local Rabbonim and they like it. However, I have not found any Rov who has said this in the past. My question is: who has said this chiddush previously?

This doesn't quite fit with Rashi (quoting the midrash) that hashem saved yishmael despite the angels protests, because he was still a tzadik. Which also happens to be the last time yishmael is referenced in vayera

@Loani you are correct but in all this story he is called naar, not Yishmael!

@YDJ yeah I noticed that too. Either that or "Ben ha'ama". There are other possible explanations though

It is likely related to the fact that the name contains the name of G-d Yishma-E-l. Good find!

@Loani That midrash doesn’t necessarily say he’s a tzaddik. Rather he just wasn’t a rasha deserving of death, but doesn’t make him a tzaddik
